# Computer lags when running video based applications

Tags: windows-7, drivers, lag

My computer is relatively new (3-4 years), has a terabyte hard disk that I haven't even scratched the surface of, and keeps lagging horribly.

It doesn't crash, because the problem (from what I have been able to tell) is in the system that puts images on the screen, not the system that connects to the internet.

So far, the problem has only happened in graphics intensive games like Minecraft, and ***even happens when I play in offline mode.*** I know the problem isn't with the games themselves because a) it has happened identically in more then one game and b) when I start to do something else that requires the loading of a video, even on YouTube, the problem persists.

The problem always fixes itself eventually, although twice my entire screen has gone black for a few seconds, after which the computer gave me an error message that said something like "The device driver has failed and been recovered." I ran scans for errors in the device drivers and got a message that said (basically) error found, let me fix it. But the problem persisted.

When the lag comes on, I cant even walk an avatar in a straight line because my actions are out of sync so badly with the image that I am seeing. I think that my actions are being put through to the system all right, just not to the screen that I look at.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you get the "driver XYZ stopped responding and has recovered".

MS provided a KB article about it:

**"Display driver stopped responding and has recovered" error in Windows 7 or Windows Vista**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2665946

Try all 3 steps and run the linked FixIt.

Answer (score 0):

Hey please check your Display drivers once as it is correctly installed or it is supported to that Hardware . Please Re-install the drivers once again based on your Hardware if the problem exists check your hardware it may be problem. Try to install separate Graphics card as you said your playing Games very well . Because of that the video memory assigned by system may be low if you reach or extended that memory the problem make occurred.

Comment: Please provide your system configuration and Hardware details so that we can give a correct answer to resolve your problem....

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about Minecraft, well.. That game is the worst coded game ever /in my opinion/ and it takes a lot of resources: ram, cpu (only one core), video and disks. Remember that it is completely sandboxed in a JVM.

First of all install the newer version of your graphic card's drivers.
Second Step: Install x64 version of Java (if you're running a 64bit version of windows).

Third step: When it starts "lagging" (wrong term, fyi) just shut Minecraft down, leave it close for 2 minutes and reopen it.